# How to dynamically load Stylesheets according to language change in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have Emberjs app which support LTR and RTL language. I use ember-intl addon to support multiple language. I want to know there is a good way to load stylesheets based on language change ?

Comment: I think this answer applies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21617814/916734. Particularly the bit about it not typically being worth the trouble. How much how big is each sheet?

Comment: you could prefix the stylesheets with a class and set this class dynamically on your <body> or other top level tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a solution

1-I added two manifest files one one or LTR and other or RTL under app/styles

2-I updated configuration in ember-cli-build.js to compile this files as stated in http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#asset-compilation

3- i updated style sheet link in index.html to include class for rtl and ltr

4- in route activate() hook i checked if lang=ltr remove rtl assets else remove ltr assets

Answer (score 0):

in the step 4 you could use [ember-meta-tags addon](https://github.com/ronco/ember-cli-meta-tags) to add the right style file to html tree according to your language.